# How do you eliminate data skew when joining large tables in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Table A has ~150M rows while Table B has about 60. In Table A, `column_1` can and often does contain a large number of NULLS. This causes the data to become badly skewed and one executor ends up doing all of the work after LEFT JOINING.

I've read several posts on a solution but I've been unable to wrap my head around the different approaches that span several different versions of Spark.

What operation to do I need to take on Table A and what operation do I need to take on Table B to eliminate the skewed partitioning that occurs as a result of LEFT JOIN?

I'm using Spark 2.3.0 and writing in Python. In the code snippet below, I'm attempting to derive a new column that's devoid of NULLs (which would be used to execute the join), but I'm not sure where to take it (and I have no idea what to do with Table B)

```
new_column1 = when(col('column_1').isNull(), rand()).otherwise(col('column_1'))

df1 = df1.withColumn('no_nulls_here', new_column1)

df1.persist().count()
```

Comment: are you joining two tables with column_1 column?